# My class library couldn't be found when I want to use it from another project

Tags: c#, class, class-library

I have a class library and I want to use it as a reference from another projects. But, when I try to create an instance of a public class wich in this library, I can't build the project. It says, type or namespace ClassLibName could not be found. (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I checked reference and add it again. I add namespace too. Do you have any suggestion about this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code that gives context to this?  Without this context, both the answers below are correct for the question you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My class library and other project had different target framework. I set them to .Net Framework4, the problem is solved. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: I think you should accept an helping solution instead of answering your own question

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that instance of the class you are trying to create is declared as **public** in the class library:

```
namespace ClassLibName 
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then inside the client project you add the assembly as reference and then

```
using ClassLibName;

...

SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
```

Comment: @cagin, then you won't have any problems instantiating them. Did you add a `using` to the namespace where the class is defined as shown in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your Library is built with a greater version of the framework than your project...

If so, you'll have to upgrade your project to build it if possible... or downgrade the library!

Answer (score 1):

Is the class you're trying to instantiate `internal` by any chance? That's the default:

```
// These are equivalent (for a top-level class)
class Foo
internal class Foo

// This is what you need
public class Foo
```

If you get rid of the code instantiating the class, but *do* keep the `using` directive for the namespace and the reference to the assembly, does it compile? If so, that would suggest it really is a problem with the specific class rather than how you're referring to the library.

Comment: @cagin: Okay, and what about the question in the second half of my answer? Is your namespace definitely correct in the `using` directive?

Comment: Yes I add the namespace to using block

Comment: @cagin: If you only answer part of what I'm asking at a time, it'll make this a longer process... if you keep the `using` directive but remove the line which tries to use the actual class, does it compile?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an using directive or you didn't add a reference to the assembly in your project, or both.

In solution explorer, right click on References, click Add references, go to Browse, select the compiled dll of the other project.

If, for example, your class is in namespace `Hello.World`, you should also add

```
using Hello.World;
```

at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I did it but the same result.